# Swift 4 UIAlertController how can I combine different actions into 1 completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

In the following code I'm checking UserDefaults. I want to react depending on the value. First question is how can I combine both cases into only 1 completionHandler? And second question is, in the completion handler, can I find the button index of the action instead of my switch being dependent on the title? Thanks in advance.

```
 func checkUser() {

    let registered = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "registered")

    switch registered {

        case true:
            let firstName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "firstName") ?? ""
            let lastName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastName") ?? ""
            var fullName: String!
            fullName = firstName
            fullName.append(" \(lastName)")

            let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Please confirm", message: "Are you \n \(String(describing: fullName))", preferredStyle: .alert)

            optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
            let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style:.destructive, handler: confirmHandler)
            let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .destructive, handler: confirmHandler)
            optionMenu.addAction(yesAction)
            optionMenu.addAction(noAction)
            let popover = optionMenu.popoverPresentationController
            popover?.delegate = self
            popover?.sourceView = view
            popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX - 100, y: self.view.bounds.midY + 100, width: 200, height: 200)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: {})
            }

        case false:
            let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Please confirm", message: "Do you want to set up this iPad?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            optionMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
            let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: setUpHandler)
            let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .default, handler: setUpHandler)
            optionMenu.addAction(yesAction)
            optionMenu.addAction(noAction)
            let popover = optionMenu.popoverPresentationController
           // popover?.delegate = self
            popover?.sourceView = view
            popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX - 150, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: {})
            }
        }
}

func setUpHandler (alert: UIAlertAction) {

    print ("received: \(String(describing: alert.title))")
    switch alert.title {
        case "Yes":
            print("show set up")
        case "No":
            print("show set up")
        default:
            print("show set up")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not give each action (button) its  own completion function, like everyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func checkUser() {

    let registered = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "registered")

    let title = "Please Confirm"
    var message:String?
    var actions:[UIAlertAction]! = []
    var rect:CGRect!

    switch registered {

        case true:
            let firstName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "firstName") ?? ""
            let lastName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastName") ?? ""
            var fullName: String!
            fullName = firstName
            fullName.append(" \(lastName)")


            let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style:.destructive, handler: confirmHandler)
            let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .destructive, handler: confirmHandler)
            actions.append(yesAction)
            actions.append(noAction)
            rect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX - 100, y: self.view.bounds.midY + 100, width: 200, height: 200)
            break

        case false:
            let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: setUpHandler)
            let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .default, handler: setUpHandler)
            actions.append(yesAction)
            actions.append(noAction)
            rect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX - 150, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            break
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
    for action in actions {
        alert.addAction(action)
    }
    let popover = alert.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.delegate = self
    popover?.sourceView = view

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func setUpHandler (alert: UIAlertAction) {

    print ("received: \(String(describing: alert.title))")
    switch alert.title {
    case "Yes":
        print("show set up")
    case "No":
        print("show set up")
    default:
        print("show set up")
    }
}
```

Create only what you NEED inside the cases. So, set some variables (what I call setup work) to establish what will CHANGE per case. Then, after ALL the work is done after the cases, present the alert.

In regards to your questions -- you should have each button with a different handler. It's 1) most readable and 2) provides it where it is not so coupled. Allows for multiple uses.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Good suggestion.